# jQuery. Переменная

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 блока. В первом блоке несколько radio с уникальным value, во втором несколько inline-block с display:none. Нужно, чтобы при выборе radio , блокам inline-block добавлялся класс .active, если у них в id тоже значение что и value у radio

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" value="1">
</div>
<div>
    <div class="one" id="1">test1</div>
    <div class="one" id="1">test2</div>
    <div class="one" id="2">test3</div>
</div>


<script> 
var MyValue = $("input:radio:checked").val();
$(".block").filter("#MyValue").addClass("active");
</script>
```

Пытаюсь решить проблему таким образом - не получается. Значение value записывается в MyValue, провреял. Но не получается подставить его в filter(). Если заместо #MyValue пишу например "#1", то работает как мне нужно - отображаются элементы с id="1"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения нужно собирать строку *подставляя значение* переменной, а не ее название

```
$('#'+MyValue).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, помогло!