# Не работает с переменной

Tags: jquery

Подскажите почему работает:

```
$(".ms-noWrap[title ='10.07.2000']").attr("style","display: none");
```

не работает:

```
var data1 ='10.07.2000';
$(".ms-noWrap[title = data1]").attr("style","display: none");
```

Comment: @Grundy скорее как сконкатенировать переменную, нежели то, что вы с Darth предлагаете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это да :-) но такой вопрос тоже был :-)

Comment: @Grundy то есть если такой вопросы был, то закроем текущий вопрос каким-нибудь дубликатом наугад?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага, потом всегда можно поменять источник дубликата :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вот например: [jQuery. Переменная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/557753/186999) и таких еще куча была, ща поищу и еще: [Передача переменной внутрь двойных кавычек JQuery, метод .load()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529626/186999)

Answer (score 1):

Для простых переменных, которые не содержат в своих значениях точки, запятые, слэши - достаточно вставить переменную в строку, сконкатинировав эту переменную с ней (потому что данные внутри кавычек`''` интерпретируются как строка. поэтому и переменная является простым текстом), либо с помощью интерполяции строк, появившейся в ES6 вставить переменную во внутрь строки.

Примеры взяты из ответа **@Darth**

```js
var data1 ='666';
var data2 ='777';

$(".ms-noWrap[title = " + data1 + "]").attr("style","background: red;");

// Интерполяция, работает с ES6
$(`.ms-noWrap[title = ${data2}]`).attr("style","background: green;");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-noWrap" title="666">10.07.2000</div>
<div class="ms-noWrap" title="777">10.07.2001</div>
```

Однако в вашем случае это не сработает, т.к. вы используете в качестве значения переменной дату, т.е. строку, содержащую точки. Парсер `jquery` парсит селектор регулярными выражениями и, видимо, это ломает ему мозг. Он не может понять откуда внезапно у атрибута `title` взялись запрещенные символы.

Поэтому для явного обозначения того факта, что нужно найти элемент, где значение атрибута `title` является строка, не зависимо от содержащих знаков, надо дополнительно обернуть переменную в кавычки. В итоге должно быть так:

```js
var data1 ='10.07.2000';
var data2 ='10.07.2001';

$(".ms-noWrap[title = '" + data1 + "']").attr("style","background: red;");
// Интерполяция, работает с ES6
$(`.ms-noWrap[title = '${data2}']`).attr("style","background: green;");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-noWrap" title="10.07.2000">10.07.2000</div>
<div class="ms-noWrap" title="10.07.2001">10.07.2001</div>
```

Пример с фильтрами не вижу смысла приводить.

Answer (score -1):

```
//1. 
$(".ms-noWrap[title = "+data1+"]").attr("style","display: none");
// 2. 
$(`.ms-noWrap[title = ${data1}]`).attr("style","display: none");
//3. 
$('.ms-noWrap').filter(index => $(this).attr("title") === data1).attr("style","display: none");
```

Comment: спасибо за замечание. считаю ваш ответ полностью исчерпывающим, посему свой удаляю)

Comment: первый вариант вроде не сработает. нужны доп. кавычки.... третий тоже какой-то странный

Comment: в общем ни один твой пример не работает) https://jsfiddle.net/zc9hrj2o/  ..... третий вообще неясен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в третьем ошибочно используются стрелочные функции. С обычными функциями все ок будет https://jsfiddle.net/zc9hrj2o/1/

Comment: Для стрелочной функции надо использовать второй параметр, а не this -> https://jsfiddle.net/zc9hrj2o/2/